# THREE.JS Camera rotation lost when Orbit control is used

Tags: camera, three.js, rotation, controls, orbit

To get you into the context, let say i have a camera

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera();
camera.position.set(1,1,1);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
camera.rotation.set(Math.PI/2, 0 ,0) // <=== this is lost when the orbit control move
```

then i create an orbit control

```
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
```

The Problem is that when i use the orbit control by dragging the mouse on click or zooming, the camera rotation is lost.

I tried using **controls.update()** but it's not working

**Edit**

Here is a link for a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o4f03mdo/)

```js
var camera;
var scene;
var conrols;
var renderer;

function init() {
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    alpha: true,
    antialias: true

  });
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 10000);
  camera.position.set(0, 0, 5);
  scene.add(camera);

  scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.6));

  var light1 = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffbb, 0x080820, 0.7)
  scene.add(light1);


  var light2 = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
  light2.position.set(4, 7, 23);
  scene.add(light2);

  var light3 = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
  light3.position.set(4, 7, -23);
  //scene.add(light3);

  var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 1, 1);
  var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color: 0x00ffff
  });
  var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(cube);

  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);


}


function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
  //console.log("position");
  //console.log(camera.position);
  //console.log("rotation");
  //console.log(camera.rotation);

  camera.rotation.set(0, 0, 1.57);
  // camera.position.set(-0.041, 1.9, -1.21);

}



init();
animate();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

<button id="button">change rotation</button>
```

in my original application i have a 3D foot mesh. Sometimes i need to have a vertical view of the backfoot with only a click. So i apply a camera rotation. but when i move the camera with orbit control the camera rotation jumps to the old value.

Comment: rather than rotating the camera, you probably want to set the `controls.target`. If you posted a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), it would be much easier to help you

Comment: @2pha  Here is the link for a jsfiddle :
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o4f03mdo/)

Comment: I am unsure what you are trying to achieve. Why rotate the camera if you are using orbit controls? And sorry, I should have asked you to attach a snippet here rather than a link to jsfiddle

Comment: Basically in my original application i have a 3D foot mesh. Sometimes i need to have a vertical view of the backfoot with only a click. So i apply a camera rotation. but when i move the camera with orbit control the camera rotation jumps to the old value.

Comment: Can you not add a second camera and switch between the two?

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to a second camera like 2pha says or you can set `controls.enableRotate = false;`